# Reversing a number in a string

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel I have some strings in certain cells. Strings look like this:

> john was born in 1002 and is now 91 years old
>
> Alissa was born in 1102 and is going to atlanta after 92 years.

I want them to look like this:

> john was born in 2001 and is now 19 years old
>
> Alissa was born in 2011 and is going to atlanta after 29 years.

I searched and found the following VBA code that reverses all strings:

```
Function Reversestr(str As String) As String
    Reversestr = StrReverse(Trim(str))
End Function
```

But I want only numbers in a string to get reversed. How can I make the function to only choose numbers in the string?

Comment: Are there always only two numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question.

Comment: @QHarr No the numbers are mostly years which are from 1 to 4 digits

Comment: @KenWhite I edited the question to be more specific. I used the code above to reverse the whole string in my excel worksheet, but seems the numbers were ok and now they are not.

Comment: I'm not convinced your edit was helpful, I'm afraid. The code you've posted makes no effort to solve the question you've asked here. (And even after an answer was posted, you asked that poster to edit it to suit your needs instead of attempting it yourself.) My original comment still applies, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will iterate column A and reverse all numbers found:

```
Sub FLIPNUM()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim rngarr As Variant
        rngarr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(rngarr, 1) To UBound(rngarr, 1)
            Dim str() As String
            str = Split(rngarr(i, 1))

            Dim j As Long
            For j = 0 To UBound(str)
                If IsNumeric(str(j)) Then
                    str(j) = StrReverse(str(j))
                End If
            Next j
            rngarr(i, 1) = Join(str, " ")
        Next i
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value = rngarr
    End With

End Sub
```

or as a function:

```
Public Function ReverseNum(rng As Range) As String
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim str() As String
    str = Split(rng.Value)

    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(str)
        If IsNumeric(str(j)) Then
            str(j) = StrReverse(str(j))
        End If
    Next j
    ReverseNum = Join(str, " ")
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can this be used as a function and called inside a cell? (like =Reversenum(A1))

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for helping me on this. Here is the link of my public calendar for this year. without your help this wasn't possible. https://calendar.google.com/calendar?cid=Y25lNXUyM3ZmOWdvcjhwb3B0YWI3b291cWNAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ

Comment: @ScottCraner Also your code had a little bug. when the numbers had a ( before them, the function ignores them.

Comment: @Euphoria you did not specify that as a possibility, or I would have accounted for it.